# Awesome multimonitor scenario: how to stop mirroring?

Tags: 12.10, xorg, awesome, xinerama

I have this two-monitor configuration that works flawlessly in the default 12.10 GNOME wm. This is my xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VGA0"
    Option "Enable" "true"
    Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1200_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LVDS0"
    Option "Enable" "true"
    Modeline "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
    Option "PrefferedMode" "1368x768_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon0"
    Driver "radeon"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon1"
    Driver "radeon"
    Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Big Screen"
    Device "Radeon0"
    Monitor "VGA0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1920x1200"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Little Screen"
    Device "Radeon1"
    Monitor "LVDS0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1368x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "My Layout"
        Screen 0 "Big Screen"
        Screen 1 "Little Screen" RightOf "Big Screen"
        Option "Xinerama" "true"
EndSection
```

However, awesome wm that I am trying to set up right now is simply mirroring upper left part of the bigger screen to the smaller screen. Although I am happy that the resolution is right, I would obviously like to fill each screen with different content.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to try another easy/reversible option, you could make a copy of your xorg.conf, and then change "true" to "off" for xinerama.

these commands should do it:

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf ~/xorg.conf
cat ~/xorg.conf | sed 's/true/off/g' > ~/xorg.conf.new
sudo cp ~/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

if something goes wrong, you can copy the original back using recovery mode and this command (edit user to be YOUR username of course)

```
sudo cp /home/user/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

the advantages of being able to use the second display are worth the effort and time to get it to work, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

i should be able to help. it's very similar to the setup i'm using. I think your problem is caused by Xinerama being on really. i suggest using the amdcccle program to configure it. You could also use lxrandr, it's very simple to use, but without installing anything else, use "gksudo amdcccle", expand the  **Display Manager** group, and click on Xinerama. make sure there is no check there. It may be grey. if it's grey, select **Display Manager**, click the down arrow in the upper right corner of the icon representing monitor 2, and select "Multi-display" and then "multi-display desktop with displays 1". go back and make sure there's no check in Xinerama.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this (I mean, installing and attempting to run amdcccle ending by an error in the command line) screwed up my system hard -- I was unable to go into graphic mode. I guess I should have been more careful -- obviously, my graphic card is either too old or I am not using the proper driver for this kind of stuff. I do not want to digg into this as I really hate low level administration of my system. :-) So I rollbacked to the previous stable state and I won't be using the smaller monitor.

Comment: I'm sorry that caused more problems and didnt fix anything. I realize you've kind of "moved on", but I'll post another possible solution. maybe it'll work without changing drivers.